# Creating partitions on ubuntu 14.04 for new windows 7 installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, uninstall

New to the forum and an ubuntu newbie.I have to install windows 7 and I currently have ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop.I already made a ubuntu live usb to completely format the disk(it will erase all my personal files but i have backups) and create ntfs partitions,but have a few questions.

1)I downloaded windows 7 pro from dreamspark account from a friend's computer.It is now sitting as an iso file on an external hard disk which also has some other personal files and documents on it.Now when I use ubuntu live usb for booting in order to partition laptop drive it will entirely erase ubuntu.

So in this case how do I install windows 7 using the iso on the external hard disk from here on?I dont have a dvd/cd to create a windows cd.

Correct me If I went wrong anywhere above and pardon me if I am asking really basic questions.But I could use some quick help here.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: I am not attempting to create dual booting, but instead I am trying to remove ubuntu entirely and install windows 7 .

Comment: Just install windows 7 as normal and you can delete the "old" ubuntu partition(s) when you select custom install on the windows 7 installation screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Windows 7 over Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/339727/)